# how can I hide this code on blade templates?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, templates

when I pass data through props on blade template

```
<posts-component :user="{{ Auth::user() }}" :profile="{{ $profile }}" :friend="{{ Auth::user()->isFriendWith($profile) ? 1 : 0 }}"></posts-component>
```

I can see the code when I use tool developer on any web browser...

[here image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XILax.png)

can I hide this code? or should I use other way?

Comment: Does this refer to a [Vue.js component](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) or a [Blade component](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#components)?

Comment: Can we see the `friend-requests-component` code before it's rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all the object properties because you pass the entire User instances to your component. When the view renders the component, it also renders the variables you've passed to your component.

`Auth::user()` and `$profile` are two instances of your User class. A User object has a number of properties (id, username, name, lastname, email, etc.). If you pass a full Object instance to your component, it will be rendered in the view, exposing all it's properties.

To avoid rendering all the properties of an object in a view, you should only call the object propertie(s) you need, and not the object itself.

For example:

```html
<posts-component :user="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" :profile="{{ $profile->id }}" :friend="{{ Auth::user()->isFriendWith($profile) ? 1 : 0 }}"></posts-component>
```

**Note:** Your `isFriendWith()` method currently accepts a User instance and returns a boolean. It's not an issue because it only returns `true` or `false` and therefore never expose User's properties.

---

To summarize, it's fine to pass objects instances from your controller to your view, but once in your view, you should be careful about rendering only the properties you are willing to expose.